# pathlib2 not working for finding files recursively

Tags: python, python-2.7, glob, pathlib

I'm using `python2.7` and trying to find files recursively in subdirectories but pathlib2 is returning NULL

```
>>> from pathlib2 import Path
>>> list(Path('~/text-segmentation/data/choi/').glob('**/*.ref'))
[]
```

Whereas if the same thing is done in `python3` by using glob module

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob('~/text-segmentation/data/choi/**/*.ref', recursive=True)
['./data/choi/2/9-11/34.ref', './data/choi/2/9-11/26.ref', './data/choi/2     
/9-11/30.ref']
```

Moreover, the following technique is also not working

```
>>> for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('~/text-segmentation/data/choi/'):
...     for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.ref'):
...             matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))

>>> matches
[]
```

I've to work in python2. Is there any workaround?

Edits: Use `/home/myuser/` instead of `~`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `PosixPath` with the `expanduser()` method instead if you want to be able to expand `~` as your home directory:

```
list(PosixPath('~/text-segmentation/data/choi/').expanduser().glob('**/*.ref'))
```

Comment: sorry, but it still returns NULL :(